# Google chrome DevTools in application tab does not show data and key

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

google chrome DevTools in application tab does not show the localhost url (http://localhost:16166/) data, is there anyone to answer this problem ? for illustration you can see the picture.

https://prnt.sc/qe0lay

Comment: It means there's no data.

Comment: yes, data does not appear, for example youtube.com data appears but when debuging my web application it does not appear, just I want to take authenticationtoken from there. https://prnt.sc/qe11p2